# MySQL: get each latest entry from joined table

Tags: mysql, join, cakephp-3.0, greatest-n-per-group

I'm trying to build a Database (SQLFiddle below) for `Items` (let them be any kind of machine, in this example cars and bikes) which *probably* have to be checked at a given interval against one or more `CheckTypes`.

An `Item` has many `ItemsCheckTypes`:

- `Item` Car1 has to be checked every 2 years at a garage and every year by sight
- `Item` Car2 has only to be checked at the garage
- `Item` Bike2 does not have to be checked at all.

A `Check` belongs to a `CheckType` and has many `ItemsChecks`:

- A `Check` on 2018-01-01 with `CheckType` "Garage inspection", Car1 & Car2 were checked (`ItemsChecks` does the assignment)

What i want now is a query to find out the **last time**, an `Item` has been checked for **each** of it's `ItemsCheckTypes`.
Expected is a result like this:

```
Items.id | CheckTypes.id | LAST CHECK.date | LAST CHECK.id
1        | 1             | 2018-01-01      | 4
1        | 2             | 2017-08-01      | 3
2        | 1             | 2016-01-01      | 1
```

I tried many JOINS, subqueries and other approaches, tried to figure out which table is my starting point (I'm thinking of `ItemsChecks` or `Items`) - but right now I just don't know if it is possible at all or should I do one of the following to (hopefully) simplify it:

- create some kind of cache / helper-table which stores the last check's id, date and type_id - being overwritten on new check assignment if date is greater than the current last date (might be a new possible source off errors)
- come up with a better database design
- do a new query for each item (which i think might be easier but wont give me the option to find all items which have to be checked soon)

On application-level I'm using CakePHP 3.x, but i doubt a Cake-solution would be easier than an SQL-solution.
The model-associations seem fine, everything else is working as expected.

Finally the SQL-Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b3d1f8/17

Any help or suggestions is appreciated, I don't know which way to go...

Comment: Sorry, i understand result  at row (1        | 2             | 2017-08-01      | 3).

Comment: Item #1 last Check for CheckType #2 was  at 2017-08-01, Check #3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group the checks by `item_id` and `check_type_id` and get the latest date:

```sql
select
    ic.item_id, 
    c.check_type_id, 
    max(c.date) latest
from items_checks ic
inner join checks c on c.id = ic.check_id
group by 
    ic.item_id, 
    c.check_type_id
;
```

`check_id` is still missing. So we take the previous select and join it with the table `checks` to get it.

```sql
select
    c2.item_id,
    c2.check_type_id,
    c2.latest last_check,
    c1.id check_id
from checks c1
inner join (
    select ic.item_id, c.check_type_id, max(c.date) latest
    from items_checks ic
    inner join checks c on c.id = ic.check_id
    group by ic.item_id, c.check_type_id
) c2 on c2.check_type_id = c1.check_type_id and c2.latest = c1.date
order by
    c2.item_id,
    c2.check_type_id
;
```

Comment: okay, I'm impressed. Give me a little time to figure out this magic, but seems to be the answer i would never have found.

Comment: @nappo `check_id` cannot be selected in the first select, because it is not grouped and it is not aggregated. So we need to do a join with the `checks` table to get the `check_id`. – So if this is what you have been looking for, will you please accept my answer. Thanks.